# PostBackTrigger for control inside Placeholder inside wizard FinishNavigationTemplate

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I'm trying to set a PostBackTrigger dynamically for a LinkButton control that's inside a Placeholder control that's inside a FinishNavigationTemplate of a Wizard. The reasono I want to do a normal postback is because the button starts a download.

My (simplified) markup looks like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="updPanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Wizard runat="server" ID="wizard">
            <WizardSteps>
                <asp:WizardStep runat="server" Title="Step 1">
                    Step data
                </asp:WizardStep>
            </WizardSteps>
            <FinishNavigationTemplate>
                <asp:Placeholder ID="phTest" Visible="false" runat="server">
                    <asp:LinkButton id="lbtnClick" runat="server" />
                </asp:Placeholder>
            </FinishNavigationTemplate>
        </asp:Wizard>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now I wan't to add the Linkbutton id as a PostBackTrigger once the PlaceHolder Visible property is set to true.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PlaceHolder phTest = wizard.FindControl("FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID$phTest") as PlaceHolder;
    phTest.Visible = true;

    LinkButton lbtnClick = offerWizard.FindControl("FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID$lbtnClick") as LinkButton;
    PostBackTrigger trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
    trigger.ControlID = lbtnClick.ID;
    //trigger.ControlID = lbtnClick.ClientID;
    //trigger.ControlID = "FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID$lbtnClick";

    updPanel.Triggers.Add(trigger);
}
```

This gives me the Exception "A control with ID 'lbtnClick' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'updPanel'."
Is there a way to keep the markup the way it is and somehow have the linkbutton do a normal postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work, but if someone has a better solution I'll gladly accept it

```
PostBackTrigger trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = "offerWizard$FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID$lbtnClick";
updPanel.Triggers.Add(trigger);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use trigger.ControlID = lbtnClick.UniqueID;